# Docker swarm with NGINX proxy and websockets

Tags: node.js, docker, websocket, swarm

I am not sure if this is achievable. I am running docker in swarm mode with the following version:

Client:
 Version:      17.03.0-ce
 API version:  1.26
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   3a232c8
 Built:        Tue Feb 28 08:10:07 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.0-ce
 API version:  1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   3a232c8
 Built:        Tue Feb 28 08:10:07 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true

I am running a stack with a websocket based application behind an NGINX reverse proxy (also in the same stack using the same overlay network)  However, I am noticing the following error.  The application is node js based.

> upstream timed out (110: Operation timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: , request: "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LiGxq_l&sid=As9AJ2pEHieTGXP6AAAC HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://x.x.x.x/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LiGxq_l&sid=As9AJ2pEHieTGXP6AAAC", host: "", referrer: ""

Obviously, the client socket connection can't resolve to the services cluster hosted in the swarm.  Is there a workaround configuration for docker swarm or it is just not possible?  I have not had much luck getting any hits searching for a solution.  Thanks for any feedback.  BTW.  single instance of the service works fine.

Comment: This sounds more like a possible nginx configuration issue. Can you give more information about the nginx image and configuration and where it sits between the request and the upstream server?

Comment: Thanks for getting back.  The NGINX is the reverse proxy.  The topology is similar to the one in the NGINX blog - https://www.nginx.com/blog/docker-swarm-load-balancing-nginx-plus/ .  My question is whether it is even possible to get a swarm to work with websockets?

Comment: The Swarm load balancer should just be LVS (Linux Virtual Server) and should just work at the IP and port level. It shouldn't care about websockets. But nginx will need to know about it. Have you configured nginx to properly upgrade if needed? https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I was looking for.  I will test it out and update.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an Image for myself, built with nodejs, named [nginx-autoconf](https://github.com/arefaslani/nginx-autoconf). It listens to docker socket and update nginx configuration automatically.